# Gitlab project cant resolve a maven dependency from another project in the same gitlab group

Tags: maven, gitlab

In my dependency project I have a `ci_settings.xml`:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Job-Token</name>
                        <value>${env.CI_JOB_TOKEN}</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

And I have configured the registry in my pom.xml:

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
            <url>${env.CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
            <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
            <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

When I run the CI pipline with the following .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
deploy:
  image: maven:3.6-jdk-11
  script:
    - mvn deploy -s ci_settings.xml
  only:
    - main
```

The dependency is getting deployed to the package repository successfully.

```
Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/model-0.0.1-20211216.121731-6.jar
Uploaded to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/model-0.0.1-20211216.121731-6.jar (35 kB at 61 kB/s)
Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/model-0.0.1-20211216.121731-6.pom
Uploaded to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/model-0.0.1-20211216.121731-6.pom (3.8 kB at 6.3 kB/s)
Downloading from gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/maven-metadata.xml (283 B at 1.6 kB/s)
Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (773 B at 1.3 kB/s)
Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/maven-metadata.xml (283 B at 455 B/s)
```

[image]

The problem appears now when I try to use that dependency in another gitlab project in the same group using the same `ci_settings.xml` which was used by the deployment. I have setup the pom like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>de.group.my</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.group.my</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

But when I the run the CI pipeline It always ends up with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project app: Could not resolve dependencies for project de.group.my:app:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact de.group.my:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven) -> [Help 1]
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact de.group.my:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.fronetic.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven
```

That happens for

- The metadata.xml
- The pom.xml
- The jar

But copying the link for the metadata.xml into the browser it is getting downlaoded:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>de.group.my</groupId>
  <artifactId>model</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20211216.121731</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>6</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20211216121731</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>0.0.1-20211216.121731-6</value>
        <updated>20211216121731</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>0.0.1-20211216.121731-6</value>
        <updated>20211216121731</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

In the logs it tries to download:

```
Downloading from gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/de/group/my/model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But this artifact does not exist. It should download `model-0.0.1-20211216.121731-6` instead but it doesnt.

Other dependencies can get downloaded (mirrored)

```
[INFO] Downloading from gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.my.de/api/v4/projects/255/packages/maven/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.5.1/micrometer-core-1.5.1.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /root/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.5.1/micrometer-core-1.5.1.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.5.1/micrometer-core-1.5.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.5.1/micrometer-core-1.5.1.pom (8.2 kB at 91 kB/s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240513/discussion-between-vonc-and-mulgard), the [OP Mulgard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2391849/mulgard) confirms:

> I solved it locally.
> I needed to **add my gitlab user to the project as a maintainer**.  Adding it to the group was not enough.
>
> But thats only for local.
>
> The gitlab build still does not run since I cant get the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` inside the docker.
> But that is a different topic I guess.

From the project members permissions, at least `Developer` is needed for [package registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/index.html) publication.

The `CI_JOB_TOKEN` problem looks like [this issue](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/maven-deploy-artifact-to-gitlab-access-denied/21838/4?u=vonc):

> We are having this exact same issue on our gitlab-ce environment, with any attempt to push with "`CI_JOB_TOKEN`" as part of a pipeline resulting in:
>
> ```
>  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) 
>  on project <our project>: 
>
>  Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.<our namespace>.spring.ext:<our jar>:0.0.1-20190207.112431-1 
>  in gitlab-maven (https://git.<our tld>/api/v4/projects/19/packages/maven) -> [Help 1]
> ```
>
> I suspect the issues are related as attempting to run the same commands from via the API directly return a 404 for unauthorised users (See: [issue 42586](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/42586)).
>
> Modifying our `settings.xml` to use a personal token with only the "`api`" scope enabled works.

Comment: Hi. I added the logs from the deployment. It is getting deployed to the correct package registry (though I dont know what a GAV is).

To use the dependency I copied the `<dependency>` and `<repositories>` config from the package registry info page of the artifact.

It seems like there is a package registry for each individual project. Isnt there a central repository for all projects on gitlab which I could use?

Comment: @Mulgard GAV means "Group Artifact Version", it is a component coordinate (sometimes completed by the packaging and the classifier): https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/using-nexus-repository/repository-manager-concepts/an-example---maven-repository-format#AnExampleMavenRepositoryFormat-ComponentCoordinatesandtheRepositoryFormat

Comment: Thank you so far. After I made sure that I use the right token the 401 got resolved. But after that we are back at the "Could not find artifact" problem. Could be the problem that I want to use the `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` dependency but there is no `SNAPSHOT` jar in the package registry at all? There are only artifacts with `model-0.0.1-<date>.<time>-<build-number>`

Comment: Nevermind. Same happens if I use `Could not find artifact de.group.my:model:jar:0.0.1-20211216.121731-6`

Comment: @Mulgard I have edited my answer to address your comments.

Comment: Thx. To specifically enable snapshots in the repository configuration of the pom.xml did not solve the problem. Still `Could not find artifact de.group.my:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: @Mulgard Can you try your `mvn` command with the `-X` option? (and / or `-E`): the goal is to look for any warning message which would explain why this repository is not properly used.

Comment: I already use it: `RUN mvn package -B -s ci_settings.xml -X -e`. Unfortunately no warnings. The repository can download other maven dependencies like `micrometer-core`. I added the logs for that to my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240513/discussion-between-vonc-and-mulgard).

Answer (score 2):

This problem baffled me and whole team for a while before we understood the root cause and the resolution.

So, we had 2 repos in GitLab within same subgroup say **SubGroup1**. **Repo1** refers to a dependency published to Package Registry of **Repo2** in the build.gradle file as shown below

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/**projectID**/packages/maven'
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
            name = project.findProperty("gitlab.token.name") ?: "Job-Token"
            value = project.findProperty("gitlab.token.key") ?: System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
        }
        authentication {
            header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem was happening as for few user's push build was failing with the error

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.example.group:artifact-name:versionname.
     Required by:
         project :
```

Apparently when few other users simply re-trigger the failed job it worked like a charm, but re-trigger won't help the users who pushed the changes. So it was looking like some magic happening somewhere.

Root cause of the problem was understood from the GitLab Token Documentation.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html

**Below is the summary of the issue**
While troubleshooting CI/CD job token authentication issues, be aware that:
When the CI/CD job token limit is enabled, and the job token is being used to access a different project:

1. The user that executes the job must be a member of the project that is being accessed.
2. The user must have the permissions to perform the action.
3. The target project must be allowlisted for the job token scope limit.

And while troubleshooting the members for which the build was failing, we found they were added in the Repo1 as a Direct Member and were not part of the Repo2.

So ideal solution is, to add them as member in the **SubGroup1** so both **Repo1** and **Repo2** can be accessed as they are within same Group and access is inherited from the Group access. This will also be helpful if new repo added to the Group, members will inherit the access automatically so less maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**: CI_JOB_TOKEN by default does not have access to the another project's Package Registry

**Solution**: {Project} > Settings > CI\CD > Token Access

1. Ensure "Allow access to this project with a CI_JOB_TOKEN" is enabled
2. Under "Allow CI job tokens from the following projects to access this project"

Enter dependent project path: {username}/{dependent project}

Example: jdoe/hello